# Почему получаю ошибку Could not execute method for android:onClick?

Tags: java, android

Работал с `DialogFragment` импорт был `import android.app.DialogFragment;`

Поменял на библиотеку поддержки `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;` теперь при вызове диалога

```
DialogStillNotFinish dialogConnection = new DialogStillNotFinish();
    dialogConnection.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку

```
10-02 20:32:23.467 9203-9203/com.fittingroom.newtimezone E/art:  Verification failed on class  com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish in  /data/data/com.fittingroom.newtimezone/files/instant-run/dex/slice- slice_1-classes.dex because: Verifier rejected class  com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish due to bad  method java.lang.Object  com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish.access$supe r(com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish,  java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[])
10-02 20:32:23.478 9203-9203/com.fittingroom.newtimezone  E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute  method for android:onClick
                                                                                at  android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onCli ck(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4909)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20390)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5775)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1009)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:804)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4909) 
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20390) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5775) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1009) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:804) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish due to bad method java.lang.Object com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish.access$super(com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) (declaration of 'com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.dialogs.DialogStillNotFinish' appears in /data/data/com.fittingroom.newtimezone/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex)
                                                                              at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.TestDeleteIt.testImagesd(TestDeleteIt.java:32)
```

когда нажимаю на строчку 293 из ошибки, то окрывается класс из библиотеки и ошибка возникает в строке метода как показано ниже

```
@Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
        if (mResolvedMethod == null) {
            resolveMethod(mHostView.getContext(), mMethodName);
        }

        try {
            mResolvedMethod.invoke(mResolvedContext, v);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

---->>> throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);    <<<--------

        }
    }
```

Почему получаю эту ошибку? Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это баг в вашей версии Instant Run - технологии, позволяющей обновлять тестируемое приложение не полностью, а лишь в тех частях, где произошли изменения.

Решить проблему можно такими способами:

1. Обновить Андроид Студию до последней версии
2. Отключить в настройках Студии Instant Run
3. Удалить приложение с устройства и задеплоить заново

Comment: Андроид Студия у меня последняя, отключать ` Instant Run` мне не нужно, а вот простая перезагрузка приложения мне помагла. Спасибо!

Comment: И еще вопрос, как вы поняли что именно в этом проблема?

Comment: @Aleksey Timoshchenko, по характерной для этой проблемы ошибке, которая находится в первой строчке вашего стектрейса